# View on top of tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building an app where I have a tableview. Now on top of that tableview I want 3 buttons. When you click on these buttons the tableview's data changes. This tableview is derived from

```
@interface MultimediaViewController : CoreDataTableViewController
```

This is using NSFetchedResultController. At the moment my storyboard looks like [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/74322780@N08/8108627410/in/photostream).

The problem I have now is that the buttons on top of my tableview dissapear when I scroll down. I can solve this by making in my storyboard the following order of rank.

- View

  - TableView
  - Button 1
  - Button 2

But then my NSFetchedResultController won't work. Because my class is derived from CorDataTableViewController.

Can anybody help me solving this annoying problem. If you need more details just ask.

Kind regards.

Comment: Why won't it work? I dont get the relation between the buttons and your controller.

Comment: If you look at the image on flickr. it works fine. But my view is like 'the first cell' in the tableview so it dissappears. What I want to do now is that it keeps on top of the view and do not dissapears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you properly, you want to have the same buttons with the same actions, but they are fixed on the top of the screen while table scrolls vertically. You can:

1. Prepare new view with new buttons, which covers table underneath.
2. Connect new buttons actions to old buttons actions to make them behave the same

This is fastest and simplest workaround i can think of now.

The view that interests you is embedded as `tableView.tableHeaderView`. You may create your own brand new view overlaying the table and move the buttons:

```
UIView *buttonsView = mainTableView.tableHeaderView;
[buttonsView removeFromSuperView];
[myOwnBrandNewOverlayView addSubview: buttonsView];
```

Thats another nasty hack, but this is all I can tell you without knowing how your superclass is built.

Comment: Yes but than my tableview won't work because my super class is of CoreDataTableviewController. And it gets a UIView.

Comment: You can then prepare your own view. As I don't know the class of CoreDataTableviewController you need to investigate on your own, which of IBOutlets it needs to have connected to work properly. Then you can prepare your own view and connect IBOutlets in your own way.

Comment: You can try moving table's header view to desired place. It is not proper way of building software, cause you should investigate IBOutlets needed first and thencnnect them to your own entire new view . At least this should work.

Comment: Can we maybe chat somewhere so I can explain my problem more in detail?

Comment: Just analyse which IBOutlets are connected and rearrange the view. This should help.